# Can I omit landing page in favor of direct app access?

Tags: mobile, web-app, browser, conversion, landing-page

I am developing my own product idea, an web/mobile application for forming a long term relationship between two people. It's in the early stages, so I don't want to expose too much information yet. I don't have much experience in the UX field, just some bits & pieces from 10+ years of web development.

- I want to target the app toward common people seeking a relationship.
- I want a human approach of the whole experience and ideally no "business feel".
- The app entry consists of a few buttons (up to 5) and no forms or inputs.
- There is no signup either (that comes later).
- The app is paid but has a free trial based on usage, not a time.

What I am trying to figure is **if a flashy landing page with a button to "start" is necessary**. Do people need to get a lot of explanations first? Do they need to know about pricing model, TOS, FAQ? Or is that unnecessary distraction that can lead them away?

Currently, I am more inclined toward making the app itself as an entry point without explaining too much.  Starting with a selection of language (with auto-detection) and then a simple visual intro with a few keypoints floating around. Followed by a few extra steps and it's ready for use without ever leaving browser/mobile. I want to explain the concept in more detail to them on the go with short contextual help/hints. Later there will be also a blog on a separate subdomain diving deeper into the related topics.

I know UX isn't an exact science. It will require feedback from users and improve them over time. But I also don't want to hinder my entrance to the market with a "*that sucks*" approach. I certainly would like to hear some opinions from experienced people here.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, landing pages are not just for providing info. Yes, it is a way to provide info but it can also act as an user interface in case the app takes longer to load on a poor connection. It is better to user a static page instead of completely depending on dynamically loaded pages. It is a way to increase the conversion rate.

There are many more uses but i think this answer would suffice in this case. You can find a lot more info out there on internet but I would let you google that :)

Comment: Thanks. Hence an idea to have a language selection first which can be fairly minimal as for the code size. And load additional assets lazily in the background and chances are it will be ready before the user decides about the language.

Comment: There you go ! The trick is to keep the user engaged while performing background activities to provide a smooth experience. Please accept my answer if this solves your problem.   I wish you a Good Luck for your product. Cheers !

Comment: No offense, but you did not say anything I wouldn't already know :) And I want to wait anyway if more people will join in with answering. The answer from Bart provided much more useful information to me.

Comment: Gotcha. No offense taken :) Looking forward to learn about more solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a similar thing for a client who wanted to release a novel app. We used a landing (or branding) page as a means of onboarding the user with minimal info and maximum feel-good content, especially when you target users through classical channels or social media campaigns. We found that a landing page prepares the user for an app that doesn't convey its value at first sight. I don't know many apps that do. The landing page should be very lightweight and aimed at conversion. The app itself should open up with the core functionality up front, inviting the user to immediately play along. If the app is clear enough, the user wouldn't need onboarding as the UX is explanatory enough, but I would include it as again, I don't know many apps that are. Onboarding in-app is a skill in itself and depends largely on the right (amount of) copy. You should give a lot of attention to that part. When I do onboarding in apps I usually include about max 3 infoscreens that the user can skip or recall at a later stage at any time.
Asking for signing up is indeed something best pushed behind. What you should aim for is progressive enhancement. It's like giving a kid just the right amount of candy, at the right time, in order to change its behaviour.

Tips on onboarding can be found here: https://usabilitygeek.com/mobile-app-onboarding-how-to-do-it-right/

You should also check articles on the NNgroup site. It's pretty standard practices on UX, as standard as UX can be ;)

Good luck with the app! And don't forget to test early and often!

Comment: Thank you. It makes total sense what you are saying. I am glad I am not totally out of my mind attempting such an approach. It's going to be a wild ride nonetheless :)